# ethzasl_icp_mapping error

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, ethzasl-icp-mapping, bumblebee

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the package "ethzasl_icp_mapping" to build a 3D map using a stereo camera. When i feed the mapper node with a pointcloud, i have the following error :

ERROR Cannot lookup TOdomToScanner(odom to /stereo_camera)

How can i resolve this ?

With : rosrun tf tf_monitor, i have :

RESULTS: for all Frames

Frames:
Frame: /odom published by /mapper Average Delay: 0.00053216 Max Delay: 0.0137875

All Broadcasters:
Node: /mapper 878.531 Hz, Average Delay: 0.00053216 Max Delay: 0.0137875

RESULTS: for all Frames

Frames:
Frame: /odom published by /mapper Average Delay: 0.000526054 Max Delay: 0.0137875

All Broadcasters:
Node: /mapper 873.915 Hz, Average Delay: 0.000526054 Max Delay: 0.0137875

..........

It appears that i have no /stereo_camera frame that is being published. How can i create it ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62950/ethzasl_icp_mapping-error/) by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2013-05-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-05-18**:
Hi i cant see the error message

**Comment by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on 2013-05-20**:
Hi Sentinal_Bias, the error that i am  getting is now in the post, can you help me with it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Run tf view_frames

it should show you a graph of all the frames if something is not connected it means a tf transform is missing. When i was using that package i was using a kinect so i just used the launch file, but if you are using a stereo camera i think you need to define a tf transform that gets you from your sensor to the body...

---

Originally posted by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) with karma: 418 on 2013-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on 2013-05-21**:
Hi, thank you Sentinal_Bias for responding, I have a Kinect too and i tryed to use the package by running the launch files. In launch/openni, i launched : "sensor.launch", "tracker.launch" and "tracker_viewer-groovy.launch". The topic "/point_map" is not being published.

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-05-25**:
you should only have to luanch tracker_viewer-groovy.launch and it will Launch the other launch files. Also i presume your ROS distribution is groovy. I use Fuerte btw